# Command not found after installing the python on Macbook Air

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-install

I am installing python on my MacBook Air, when I run `python` on the terminal then I am getting

> command not found

I have tried the below steps to install the python

1. Downloaded python 3.10.5 from the official website
2. I open the file which downloaded and Clicked on Continue

[image]

3. then I got below the screen and clicked on Continue

[image]

4. Again I clicked on Continue and it's asking for terms and conditions. I clicked on Agree

[image]

5. After clicking on Agree then I clicked on customize button and I got below the screen and then I clicked on install

[image]

6. It's started processing the file

[image]

7. After that, I got a successful message

[image]

8. it's opening the folder automatically

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the command `python3`, not python.